# Is there an --des-key-file equivalent for AES?

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

When you use the **`DES_ENCRYPT/DES_DECRYPT function`** in mySQL you can point to your keyfile from my.cnf using the `--des-key-file variable`.
 
I thought this should also exist for

```
AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT
```

So I searched for hours but couldn't find it: is there an equivalent for AES for this?

Comment: @Maarten: Hmm? Generally, [tag:mysql] questions are considered on-topic for SO.  Anyway, AFAICT, the answer seems to be "no".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html), no such option exists for `AES_ENCRYPT`.  Instead, you are supposed to pass the key as a parameter directly in the query.

[This answer on DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58617) suggests writing a User Defined Function that returns the key as one possible work-around.

Alternatively, you might want to consider not using the MySQL AES functions at all, and instead just doing all encryption and decryption in the client application.  One potential advantage of such an approach is that, in order to obtain and decrypt the data, an attacker then needs to compromise *both* your database and your application.